# Php query mongo for nested records

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm new to mongo. I'm working on a small site for managing a food storage database. When I query the database for key:value pairs I'm getting results but when I need to find sub values, e.g. key:{key:value}, I get nothing. Here is my record structure;

```
> db.foodstore.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5359676224333f529df761"),
        "shelf" : "1",
        "food" : "green beans",
        "container" : {
                "type" : "can",
                "size" : "#10"
        },
        "dateIn" : "09/20",
        "quantity" : "6"
}
```

Here is the php page code to query it:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$connection = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $connection->everything->foodstore;
echo "<div align='center'>";
$result = $collection->find([]);
echo "<table>";
foreach ($result as $entry){
        echo "<tr><td>",$entry['shelf'],
                "</td><td>",$entry['food'],
                "</td><td>",$entry['dateIn'],
                "</td><td>",$entry['container.size'],
                "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

The values for shelf,food, dateIn display fine but I cannot get container.size to show any value. Can anyone see where I'm screwing this up?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just change `$entry['container.size']` to `$entry['container']['size']`

Comment: Geez! That did it. Thanks so much Slava.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code like:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$connection = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $connection->everything->foodstore;
echo "<div align='center'>";
$result = $collection->find([]);
echo "<table>";
foreach ($result as $entry){
        echo "<tr><td>",$entry['shelf'],
                "</td><td>",$entry['food'],
                "</td><td>",$entry['dateIn'],
                "</td><td>",$entry['container']['size'], //here changed
                "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```